# Getting called method instance based on name/signature using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a **JQuery** plugin that scans for attributed instructions and does some internal wire up of routines. We would like to allow content owners to provide us with a *Name* of a method that matches a predefined signature which we will call within our process at the appropriate time.

At design time you might normally do something like this:

`myplugin.callback = function (){ /* Do stuff */ }`

We want the caller to describe the reference and we will scan it and set things up once the DOM is ready. Something like the following:

**Content owner defines their intent**

`<div callback="MyMethodName">`

**We find the instruction and then attach it to the required callback point in our plugin**

`var methodRef = ?????; 
myplugin.callback = methodRef`

Is there a mechanism in JQuery to find a method by its name/signature and create an invokable reference to it?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Comment: sounds like a bad idea due to possible scoping issues.